# How to change the resolution of the TTY on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, vmware-player

I followed the Arch beginner's wiki to install on VMWare player (host is Windows 7) Arch without x-server and I would like to know how I can change the resolution of what I think is called the TTY to make the VMWare window fit better on my desktop. Currently it takes about 80% of my 1600x900 resolution. I'd like for it to look like a normal open console window.

Comment: An ugly workaround is to install `openssh`, start it via `systemctl enable sshd.service`, and connect to it using PuTTY.

Comment: Take a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grub#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution if you are using grub (2) I'm not sure if it'll work though.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose resolution editing GRUB configuration file **/etc/default/grub**

`GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32`

Also check this parameter to allow the kernel use the same resolution used by grub:

`GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep`

Than run following command in Arch to activate changes:

`# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

[See GRUB documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution)

Comment: Very helpful for a person that uses Syslinux. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your framebuffer: 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uvesafb

Answer (score -1):

To return the different resolutions and their associated modes run:

```
hwinfo --framebuffer
```

then <s>add the mode to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line in your grub config</s>

e.g.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="vga=0x0317"
```

---

**Note:** [This method is now deprecated.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution)

Comment: Not particularly useful for non GRUB users (e.g. syslinux / refind)

Answer (score -1):

You might find more help in [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119015) on the Arch forums.

Edit: After thinking some more, I've realized that with VMware you're likely not using GRUB. I think [this reply](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=934432#p934432) to the aforementioned post in the Arch forums may be just what you need. It involves downloading a package with pacman and changing some kernel settings. (original link to GRUB solution removed due to reputation link limit)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You may want to improve your answer by summarizing the posts you are linking to. This helps protect against link rot, and will make your answer more useful.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll edit the answer as soon as I'm at a computer.